# Making A Beep in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, beep

Is there any ways to make a beep sound in C# WPF?

I've been looking for WPF beeping, but all I could find was Beeping in normal windows form.

Comment: Have you tried the normal beep? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can make a "beep" sound using:

```
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// Plays the sound associated with the Beep system event.
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
```

This works in WPF ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.beep(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.systemsounds.beep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 7):

```
 Console.Beep(3000,200)
```

Here's the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep)

BTW, this is not just restricted to console applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can play any thing:

```
SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(filePath);
snd.Play();
```